# Does language influence thinking skills or cognition

Tags: psycholinguistics, cognitive-linguistics, sapir-whorf-hypothesis

I have an intuition, and Hypothesis, that the native language we speak is responsible for our cognition and thinking skills.

e.g. Hebrew speaking people would have poor spatial ability compared to Sanskrit speakers because Hebrew has a simple morpho-spatial structure compared to Sanskrit.

If we come to the mathematics language domain, then it's very clear that different representations are comprehended differently by the human mind, and that we are better able to think in, say, the "geometrical domain". Hence transforming a problem to different domain is a common practice in mathematics to ease understanding of the problem and solve it efficiently.

e.g: It's easier to prove a certain theorem geometrically than algebraically

Also, it could be the other way round: our cognitive abilities could determine the language that would fit our ability, making language dependent on the innate cognition of the human mind.

Comment: I think your question is too vague to be answered with a yes or no. Also, this topic is considered extrememly controversial. You'll have many academics, mainly psychologists (not Pinker) and anthropologists, saying that language does determine/influence thought. On the other hand, many linguists and philosophers would probably say that it doesn't. My suggestion is this: go and check some references on pro and anti-whorfian literature and then you can start your own way.

Comment: Are you asking whether native language influences your intelligence? In that case, this question would be [a duplicate](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2889/111). Let me know if I misunderstood your intention. :)

Comment: not necessarily intelligence but cognition is much more then that, it may even include motor skills

Comment: @Ali Ok :) I was asking just to be sure.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that native speakers of languages with shorter numerals tend to remember more numbers in average. I can not provide any evidence unfortunately.

Comment: I have an intuition that our cognition and thinking skills influence the language that we speak. It's hard to tell them apart, after all.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is a variant of the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](http://linguisticmystic.com/2006/12/31/proving-or-disproving-the-sapir-whorf-hypothesis-in-three-steps-a-quick-and-easy-guide/), which is generally not highly regarded anymore. However, it is widely recognized that people do construct categories that [correspond to their language's words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) for plants, animals, body parts, etc.